# Okta Sign In Widget redirect back to original page after login

Tags: javascript, okta, okta-api

I've been trying to find code examples that show how to redirect the user back to their original page after logging in via the Okta Sign In widget.

If a user is sitting on a SAML enabled app and clicks login, they are redirected to the a page that has the Okta sign in widget.  After a successful login, how do I send them back to the page where they clicked login?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly from their website:

```
  <!-- Script to init the widget -->
  <script>
    var orgUrl = 'https://dev-144769.oktapreview.com';
    var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({baseUrl: orgUrl});

    oktaSignIn.renderEl(
      { el: '#okta-login-container' },
      function (res) {
        if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') { res.session.setCookieAndRedirect(orgUrl); }
      }
    );
  </script>
```

in this case the var 'orgUrl' defines the redirect URL for a successful login.

redefine orgUrl to be whatever the url you would like to provide is.

```
var orgUrl = "https://showme.this.com" //like this
```

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was I was not able to see where the fromURI gets set.  Turns out that comes from Okta when you configure an app in the admin.